# Where are the stats for the Condemner Boltgun?

Tags: weapons, dark-heresy-1e

The Agent of Reliquary 26 in "Dark Heresy: Daemon Hunter" has the possibility to receive a Condemner Bolt Gun and Silver Stake.

I looked in all the books I could, but could not find any mention of those.

In which book can I find a reference to those items?

Answer (score 3):

Fantasy Flight Games forgot to put the stats in that book and never included it in any other book or errata.  Given the frequency with which they make these kinds of errors and their typical responses, you can probably contact the developers with a polite email and they will send you the stats (and probably put them in the next errata).